# Python: Visualize duplicates rows with horizontal lines from Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to accomplish that the following R code does, but using Python. The idea is to visualize as horizontal black lines the duplicated rows in a dataframe. I think I can use the `pandas.core.series.Series` that gives `df.duplicated()` (with True and False values), but I don't know how to create the plot.

Here is the R code and the resultant plot:

```
# get the row numbers of duplicated rows
duplicated_rows <- data_frame(duplicated = duplicated(ign_data), row = 1:nrow(ign_data)) %>%
    filter(duplicated == T)

# Plot duplicated rows as black lines
ggplot(duplicated_rows, aes(xintercept = row)) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = row)) + # plot a black line for each duplicated row
    ggtitle("Indexes of duplicated rows") + # add a title
    coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse() #flip x & y axis and reverse the x axis
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using pandas and matplotlib like this ;

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

duplicated_rows = pd.DataFrame({
    'duplicated': ign_data.duplicated(),
    'row': range(1, len(ign_data) + 1)
})


duplicated_rows = duplicated_rows[duplicated_rows['duplicated']]

plt.figure()
plt.vlines(duplicated_rows['row'], ymin=0, ymax=1, colors='black')
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.title('Indexes of duplicated rows')
plt.xlabel('Row index')
plt.ylabel('Duplicated')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't show that I want. The lines are vertical and the axis doesn't have the index of each row.

Comment: I've changed by `hlines` but still I can't get the same result as in the image with respect to the axis.

Comment: To get the index of each row add xdata value like this ;  plt.hlines(duplicated_rows['row'], ymin=0, ymax=1, xdata=duplicated_rows.index, colors='black')

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work because it should be `xmin`, `xmax`,  and also `xdata` doesn't exist. However, it guided me. Also, instead of using the first parameter, I used `duplicated_rows.index` and I think I'm close (still I can't replicate the vertical axis with an automatic way to adapt the values that it shows...